# Query help in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have the below table, with empid, deptid, and Name. I need to get the results as
empid,deptid,name and count of employees in each department.

```
CREATE TABLE emp(empid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, deptid INTEGER, NAME TEXT);
/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO emp VALUES
(1,100,'Tom'),
(2,200,'Lucy'),
(3,300,'Frank'),
(4,100,'Jane'),
(5,400,'Robert');
```

I need to get the results as empid,deptid,name, and count of employees in each department as below.

[image]

I am able to achieve results using the below queries.

```
SELECT a.empid, a.deptid, a.Name, result.emp_dept_count FROM emp a, 
    ( SELECT b.deptid, COUNT(b.deptid) AS emp_dept_count FROM emp b 
                  GROUP BY b.deptid ) result  
WHERE a.deptid = result.deptid;                 
/* using common table expression */
WITH emp_dept_count_cte(deptid,emp_dept_count) AS ( SELECT b.deptid, COUNT(b.deptid) AS emp_dept_count FROM emp b 
                  GROUP BY b.deptid )
SELECT a.empid, a.deptid, a.Name, result.emp_dept_count 
FROM emp a, (SELECT deptid, emp_dept_count FROM emp_dept_count_cte) result 
WHERE a.deptid = result.deptid;
/* using common table expression */
WITH emp_dept_count_cte (deptid,emp_dept_count) AS ( SELECT b.deptid, COUNT(b.deptid) AS emp_dept_count FROM emp b 
                  GROUP BY b.deptid )
SELECT a.empid, a.deptid, a.Name, emp_dept_count_cte.emp_dept_count 
FROM emp a
INNER JOIN emp_dept_count_cte
ON a.deptid = emp_dept_count_cte.deptid;
/* using common table expression */
WITH emp_dept_count_cte (deptid,emp_dept_count) AS ( SELECT b.deptid, COUNT(b.deptid) AS emp_dept_count FROM emp b 
                  GROUP BY b.deptid )
SELECT a.empid, a.deptid, a.Name, emp_dept_count_cte.emp_dept_count 
FROM emp a
LEFT JOIN emp_dept_count_cte
ON a.deptid = emp_dept_count_cte.deptid;
```

Is it possible to do this in alternate ways?

Comment: Run EXPLAIN EXTENDED [your query] on your first query, followed by SHOW WARNINGS;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for CTE. Just do

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY deptid) AS emp_dept_count FROM emp
```

Answer (score 1):

You are describing a window count:

```
select e.*, 
    count(*) over(partition by deptid) as emp_dept_count
from emp e
```

In pre-8.0 MySQL versions, where window functions are not supported, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*,
    (select count(*) from emp e1 where e1.deptid = e.deptid) as emp_dept_count
from emp e
```

Or you can join an aggregate query:

```
select e.*, d.emp_dept_count
from emp e
inner join (select deptid, count(*) as emp_dept_count from emp group by deptid) d on d.deptid = e.deptid
```